# How to use the weights of a session to initialize the weights of a new session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a question about tensorflow;
my network stricture is fixed but I want to train it with many different cases due to some local features of each case; since the inputs (different cases) are "similar", I want to use the training results of the previous one to initialize this new learning.
What I have tried is the following (I simplify my code), does anyone have some better idea of implementing this? Thank you

```
   cae_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(some size))

   cae_out = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,(some size))

   out = some_function(cae_in) 

   loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(out-cae_out))

   optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

   init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       init_op.run()

       for inx in range(all_cases):
           feed_in = some array[i]
           feed_in2 = some array[i]

           for iteration in range(0,n_iterations):
               sess.run([optimiser], feed_dict = {cae_in: feed_in,cae_out:feed_in2})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to save you trainable variables after you finish one session in a checkpoint:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())

with tf.Session():
    ...
    saver.save()
```

And restore from that checkpoint before starting another training.

Comment: Thank you @selivonchyk! I check some documentation of Saver and am now clear about how to implement it.